# Can I use LVCMOS output crystal in 50 ohm system

Tags: pll, vco, lvcmos

I have a 50 ohm clocking system in a very low noise environment (RADAR). I want to use a Abracon 100 MHz VCXO ([this one](https://hu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/3/ABLNO-1774945.pdf)), which has a 3.3V LVCMOS output. Below you can see the block diagram of the implementation.
[image]

Previously I measured the output of the mentioned Abracon VCXO that if I terminate the output with 50 ohm it produces 10 dBm signal.

**My question**: Despite the fact that the LVCMOS output crystal can drive the 50 ohm system, are there any downsides of this implementation? (e.g.: worse aging, degradation of phase noise over the years etc..)

Comment: Your so-called *LVCMOS output crystal* is not a crystal (it's an oscillator) and, the maximum load is 15 pF. There is no mention in the data sheet of it driving 50 ohm.

Comment: If there's a doubt, best to contact Abracon to obtain device specific technical support ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That oscillator is putting out a *square wave* which has an horrible amount of harmonics. Don't know if it would be able to work with it.

Anyway, 10dBm are 10mW i.e. on less than 15mA on 50 ohm at 0.7V.
For an LVCMOS it seems to me a little too much loaded since nominally it should give 0.9*Vdd (about 3V).

IMHO that oscillator is not going to be happy in the long run; it could work flawlessy forever too, it all depends on its output stage. Ask Abracom since it's really not designed for that.

Probably you can use an L-pad to match the output but if it's a digital output stage the output impedance will be everything but linear. AN408 from SkyWorks *could* give some ideas (but their product is significatively different)